# Telerik ComboBox real time search in Items (IsComboBoxEditable allow just to search from start)

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, datagridviewcolumn, radcombobox

I'm currious if it is possible to check (while writing in combobox) if an item containts phrase not only starts by and how to achieve this effect ?

Comment: Please read through the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page *before* posting any questions on StackOverflow. Your question does not have enough information in it and is unclear. Please edit it and add code examples of your efforts to achieve this so far.

Comment: use the RegEx class to define desired input patterns and capture matches when the user changes the value in your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is a AutoCompleteBox control...
Check the following demos regarding this control..It will help you get started..

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx